# EJB3 interceptors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

I have been looking into how interceptors can be applied to session beans etc in EJB3.0. Can these be applied to servlets as well?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Pascal has the right info.  (gentle nudge to try the 'accept' feature of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 5):

A good standard interceptor in a servlet container is a Servlet [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). See [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

Comment: Very interesting i will play with it. Thanks a lot for the response